# What is the license you need to publish to Xbox 360 from Unity3D?

Tags: xna, unity, licensing, xbox

I have a license for deploying and releasing games using XNA.
What is the license I need to deploy and publish games using Unity3D, and how do I get it? 
I have found very little and unclear information about how to publish to Xbox360 from Unity3D, and I can't come up with search words to get this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unity for consoles is only available to you if you are also a licensed developer for that console. Once you have such a license from the platform vendor (Microsoft, in this case), you can contact Unity for further details via their [contact form](http://unity3d.com/company/contact/get-in-touch) (this is the advice they give you on [this page](http://unity3d.com/unity/multiplatform/consoles)).

Unity doesn't build on XNA, and having the ability to publish to the 360 via XNA does not qualify you for the use of Unity on the 360. You need to be a fully-licensed developer for the platform, with access to the XDK, et cetera.

Microsoft's Xbox developer portal is [here](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/developers/home). You may want to read their FAQs.